# Update User attributes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, updates

I'm new in Ror,

I m developing an app containing sellers and buyers. 
I m using device. I distinguish them with an enum attribute state:
 (state:0 for buyer state:1 for seller) 
I would like from my admindashboard to update an User attribute from buyer to seller with a simple button publish.
I don't have any error, but the update is not done :-(
Thks in advance
Here is my code:

admindashboard.html.erb:

```
    <% @sellerwaitinglist.each do |user| %>
    <ul>
    <li><strong><%= link_to user.pseudo, user_path(user) %> <%= user.state %></strong> (<%= user.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %>)
    <br>
    <span class="label label-success"><%= link_to "passer en vendeur", user_to_seller_path(user.id), method: :patch %></span>
    <br>
    </li>
    </ul><% end %>
```

Pages Controller:

```
def user_to_seller
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.state = 0
    @user.state = 1
    @user.save
  end
  redirect_to :admindashboard if @user.save
end
```

Application Controller:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: %i[pseudo address distance choice])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: %i[pseudo avatar phone address distance description starseller email password password_confirmation state])
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
  patch '/user_to_seller/:id' =>'pages#user_to_seller', as: :user_to_seller
```

Comment: I can't see any errors? What do you see in your terminal (Rails server window) when you push the button? - and by the way, i would recommend using the [enum-way](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).. For example: `if @user.buyer?` and next line: `@user.seller!` for more readable code. -- + **Are you sure the button you're are clicking is a 'buyer' user?**

Comment: If nothing is shown. This would be a good way to get to know [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) or [Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug). You could plant one of these in your controller to see what's going on.

Comment: Great That's working now with: user.buyer? & user.seller!   Thks

Comment: I think that the problem is in you `if` statement you should use `==` and not one equal sign. so use `if @user.state == 0` instead of `if @user.state = 0`. anyway, the enum-way solution is the correct one!